# URL scheme to make Eclipse open the source code of a class

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse market have these links which can be dragged into Eclipse to install packages. I am wondering is there something similar to open the source of a class.

I want to use them in my coding notes so I can quickly jump to the source code.